# Full height of content in listview with ItemsWrapGrid as panel template windows 10 app

Tags: xaml, uwp, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

I am trying to have the content of gridview cell to stretch the height so there is no scrolling within the cell.

Here's my code:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1" Padding="50 10 50 10">
    <ListView IsTapEnabled="False"
        Background="White"
        SizeChanged="categoryListView_SizeChanged"
        x:Name="categoryListView"
        Height="auto"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource stores}, Path=CollectionGroups}"
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CategoriesList}">
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <ItemsWrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

and here is my data template:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="CategoriesList">
    <Grid x:Name="AlphabetGrid" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0 0 20 0">
        <TextBlock x:Name="CategoryName" FontSize="24" Text='{Binding Group.Key}' Foreground="#412141" FontWeight="Bold"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextAlignment="Left"/>
        <Grid Margin="0 30 0 0">
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Group.Items}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Margin="0">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" x:Name="unit_number" FontSize="15"  Text='{Binding unit}' Foreground="red"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextAlignment="Left"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" x:Name="name" FontSize="15"  Text='{Binding name}' Foreground="red"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextAlignment="Left"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

How can I achieve this? Any recommendations?
This is how it looks right now.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce your issue: it seems that **ItemsWrapGrid** uses some strange logic when row heights are calculated automatically. You can set its **ItemHeight** property manually to avoid this problem, but this solution is far from being elegant.

Alternatively you can use the [WrapPanel XAML Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwpcommunitytoolkit/controls/wrappanel) from the [UWP Community Toolkit](https://github.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit) as an **ItemsPanelTemplate** for your **ListView** to make the items stretch their height to fit the content

```
<ListView>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <controls:WrapPanel/>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ListView>
```

however, your grid is going to have a lot of empty space then
[image: WrapPanel horizontal orientation, items by categories]

If that's not what you want, you can eliminate most of the empty spaces by changing the orientation of the **WrapPanel** from horizontal to vertical

[image: WrapPanel vertical orientation, items by categories]

and even further by not grouping your items into separate controls by category

[image]